# How to use pcre2_match with binary subject data

Tags: c, pcre

I am seeking clarification on using `pcre2_match`.

*Background: I'm searching for unicode text fragments inside binary files, case-insensitive, with PCRE2.*

The declaration of this function:

```
int pcre2_match(const pcre2_code *code, PCRE2_SPTR subject,
  PCRE2_SIZE length, PCRE2_SIZE startoffset,
  uint32_t options, pcre2_match_data *match_data,
  pcre2_match_context *mcontext);
```

The man page for this function then states:

> The length and startoffset values are code units, not characters.

Now, when the subject data is binary, I cannot determine the code units because the data is not necessarily in any clean UTF format. Thus I cannot determine the code units.

All I know is the number of bytes for the subject data. And there seem to be no option by which I can tell the function that it'll be looking at binary data.

How do I ensure that this function understands that I'm passing the number of bytes so that it won't attempt to detect code points and thereby possibly exceed or shorten the amount of memory I want it to search?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe that `length` and `startoffset` are *not* byte counts.  What makes you think they are not?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting that man page statement. How would you know the length anyway?  A `char` in C is not a character either =D

Comment: @Jason They're not byte counts in the (unlikely) case that OP is using the 16 bit or 32 bit code unit versions of the library. See the introduction at  http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code units are the atomic fragments of the input. As for pcre2_match_8, it is byte, pcre2_match_16, it is uint16_t, etc. If you pass the invalid utf option, you can search binary data, but only utf8 from any byte position. If you search utf16, it will search from every second byte. Natural alignment is a cpu requirement, and PCRE must honor it.

Comment: Ah, now that makes sense. After you mentioning the specialized `_8' etc. functions, I found https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC13 which explains this. So it appears that I can safely assume that I'm working with byte units by linking against `libpcre2-8`.